# VUE Change append icon after axios response

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js

i have vue data-table which have column named quality (dropdown with append icon) i need to change append icon after get axios response(successfully update data) if dropdown changed in each row. Here my code:

```
<v-data-table>
...
<template v-slot:item.quality="props">
 <v-select
   v-model="props.item.quality"
   :items="['100', '95', '90','85', '80','75', '70']"
   :append-icon="icon"
    ref="nilais"
   @update:modelValue="editData(props.item.id,props.item.quality)"
   return-object        
></v-select>
```

This is my script

```
 export default {

      data: () => ({
       icon:'mdi-close',
      }),
      method:(){

         editData(id, nilai){
          axios.post('http://localhost/vue1/action.php', {
    action:'one', id:id,nilai:nilai
   }).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data)

  this.$refs.nilais.appendIcon='mdi-check-bold' // this is not work, error: Attempting to mutate prop "appendIcon". Props are readonly

    });
  }
        },
}
```

this is my expected result (icon changed after update data)
[image]

Comment: `this.icon='mdi-check-bold'`

Comment: @AliIsmaeel, it change all icon, i need change only updated row with dropdown change

Comment: :append-icon="item.quality? 'mdi-check-bold':'mdi-close'"